# Prove the sequence $\{\frac{1}{a_n}\}\,\, (n\geq 1)$ is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given that $\{a_n\}$ ($n\geq 1$) is a Cauchy sequence, prove that if there exists an $r$ greater than $0$ such that for all $n$ in the natural numbers $a_n$ is greater than $r$, then  $\{\frac{1}{a_n}\}\,(n\geq1)$ is Cauchy by using the definition of Cauchy.

I know that the definition of a Cauchy sequence is if for every positive real number ε, there is a positive integer $ℕ$ such that for all natural numbers $m,n>N,\,
∣x_m−x_n∣<ϵ$ then it is Cauchy; but I am unsure of how to prove that the above sequence is Cauchy.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|a_n - a_m| < r^2 \epsilon$ for all $n,m \ge N$. Thus, for all $n,m\ge N$, $$\left\lvert \frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{a_m}\right\rvert = \frac{|a_n - a_m|}{|a_na_m|}  < \frac{|a_n - a_m|}{r^2} < \frac{r^2 \epsilon}{r^2} = \epsilon.$$

Comment: Technically you should also be requiring $m \geq N$, but this is fairly minor.

Comment: @Ian thanks for spotting those typos!